# Did Lady Tremaine kill Anastasia and Drizella’s biological father?

Tags: disney, disney-princess

So, just to clarify, I’m only talking about the 1950 animated classic. We know from all 3 *Cinderella* movies that Lady Tremaine is obsessed with wealth and power and she even says “Love has nothing to do with it if power is involved.” So, *did* she kill Sir Francis Tremaine (assuming he was already called that)?

Comment: I've removed the tag from the title, that is why we have tags please don't add them into the title. I also removed the second question, if you have another question please ask it.